# Release configuration could not find dll

Tags: visual-studio, build, release

I have external dll in References (maybe it is not important, but it is Npgsql), which have

```
Copy Local = True
```

In **Debug configuration** my project successfully built.

But when I switch to **Release configuration** an error occurred:

> The type or namespace name 'Npgsql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: compare the debug vs release setting, it is most probably you miss something in release which exist in debug

Comment: I have compared settings in Configuration Manager. Where else I can see any of the settings?